# Hibernate - Primary key issuses - Persisting object to mySQL database don't work

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, web-development-server

I'm developing a '''simple''' web application project and to handle model and database I'm using Hibernate; in particular this is a block notes app online, so in the database I have a user table and a todo table:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `to-do-app`;
USE `to-do-app`;

CREATE TABLE `user`(
    username    VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
    `password`  VARCHAR(30)     NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(username)
);

CREATE TABLE todo (
    todo_id     INT         AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id     VARCHAR(20),
    content     TEXT,
    done        boolean,
    PRIMARY KEY(todo_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES `user`(username)
);
```

***PROBLEM***
I'm having issues with todo table in Java when I perform testing on the classes that handle the table.

The following classes are the ones I'm using:
**TestTodoRepository**

```
import com.example.todoapp.model.TodoRepository;
import com.example.todoapp.model.beans.Todo;
import com.example.todoapp.model.beans.User;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.FixMethodOrder;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.runners.MethodSorters;

@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class TestTodoRepository {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
    private Session session = null;

    @BeforeAll
    static void setupFactory() {
        sessionFactory = TestConfig.setupFactory(Todo.class);
    }

    @BeforeEach
    void setupSession() {
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
    }

    @AfterEach
    void closeSession() {session.getTransaction().commit();}

    @AfterAll
    static void closeFactory() {
        sessionFactory.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void test1AddTodo() {
        TodoRepository todoRepository = new TodoRepository();

        //  Try adding to-do to user that exists
        Todo todo = new Todo("antonino", "Hello World");
        System.out.println("I will add: " + todo);
        Assert.assertTrue(todoRepository.addTodo(todo));

        todoRepository.closeTodoRepository();
    }

    @Test
    public void test2ExistsTodo() {
        TodoRepository todoRepository = new TodoRepository();

        //  Try finding existing to-do
        Todo toDo = new Todo("antonino", "Hello World");
        Assert.assertTrue(todoRepository.existsTodo(toDo));

        //  Try finding not existing to-do


        todoRepository.closeTodoRepository();
    }

    @Test
    public void test3GetTodosForUser() {
        TodoRepository todoRepository = new TodoRepository();

        User test_user = new User("antonino", "antonino");
        Assert.assertNotNull(todoRepository.getTodosForUser(test_user));

        todoRepository.closeTodoRepository();
    }


}
```

**TODO**

```
package com.example.todoapp.model.beans;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;

@Entity(name = "todo")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Todo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "todo_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    /*@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)*/
    private String user_id;

    @Column(name = "content")
    private String content;

    @Column(name = "done")
    private boolean done;

    public Todo(String user_id, String content) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
        this.content = content;
        this.done = false;
    }
}
```

**TodoRepository**

```
package com.example.todoapp.model;

import com.example.todoapp.model.beans.Todo;
import com.example.todoapp.model.beans.User;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.Metadata;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;


import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TodoRepository extends Repository{

    public TodoRepository() {super();}

    /**
     * Add a to-do to the database, used to register new users
     * @param todo: the to-do entity
     * */
    public boolean addTodo(Todo todo) {
        //  if to-do exists can't add a new one
        if (em.find(Todo.class, todo.getId()) != null)
            return false;

        try {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.persist(todo);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (EntityExistsException ex) { return false; }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Checks if a to-do exists in a database
     * @param todo : contains credentials to test
     * */
    public boolean existsTodo(Todo todo) {
        return em.find(Todo.class, todo.getId()) != null;
    }

    /**
     * WORK IN PROGRESS
     * Gets to-do list based on user id (username)
     * @param user : the owning the to-do
     * */
    public
    List<Todo> getTodosForUser(User user) {
        List<Todo> toDos;

        try {
            Query findToDos = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM todo WHERE todo.user_id = :user_id");
            findToDos.setParameter("user_id", user.getUsername());

            toDos = (List<Todo>) findToDos.getResultList();
            for(Todo t : toDos)
                System.out.println(t);

            return toDos;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void closeTodoRepository() {
        super.closeEntityManager();
        super.closeEntityManagerFactory();
    }
}
```

**Repository**

```
package com.example.todoapp.model;

import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import jakarta.persistence.Persistence;

/**
 * Abstract class that represents a repository of a database entity
 * */
public abstract class Repository {
    protected final EntityManager em;
    protected final EntityManagerFactory emf;

    public Repository() {
        this.emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("to-do-app");
        this.em = emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    protected void closeEntityManager() {
        em.close();
    }

    protected void closeEntityManagerFactory() {
        emf.close();
    }
}
```

I think that also the following configuration files and stack trace will be needed:
**Stack trace**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: id to load is required for loading

    at org.hibernate.event.spi.LoadEvent.<init>(LoadEvent.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.event.spi.LoadEvent.<init>(LoadEvent.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.loader.access.IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.doLoad(IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.loader.access.IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.lambda$load$1(IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.loader.access.IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.perform(IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.loader.access.IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:2336)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:2298)
    at com.example.todoapp.model.TodoRepository.addTodo(TodoRepository.java:28)
    at TestTodoRepository.test1AddTodo(TestTodoRepository.java:46)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:42)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:80)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

**Todo.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <!-- name:full path to class:-->
    <!-- table: table name: (can be omitted. Use the class name as the table name.)-->
    <class name="com.example.todoapp.model.beans.Todo" table="todo">
        <!--Primary key-->
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long" column="todo_id"></id>

        <!-- Attributes -->
        <property name="user_id" column="user_id" type="java.lang.String"/>
        <property name="content" column="content" type="java.lang.String"/>
        <property name="done" column="done" type="java.lang.Boolean"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- jdbc driver -->
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/to-do-app</property>
        <!-- database url -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">myroot</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">mypassword</property>


        <!-- Load map file -->
        <mapping resource="com/example/todoapp/model/beans/config/User.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="com/example/todoapp/model/beans/config/Todo.hbm.xml"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<persistence xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="3.1">
    <persistence-unit name="to-do-app">
        <!-- Implementation for JPA Provider -->
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

        <!-- persistence properties configuration -->
        <properties>
            <!-- jdbc driver -->
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <!-- database url -->
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/to-do-app"/>
            <!-- database username -->
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.user" value="myroot"/>
            <!-- database password -->
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.password" value="mypassword"/>
            
            <!-- other properties -->
            <!--Print sql statement-->
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value = "false" />
            <!--Format sql-->
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value = "true" />

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**FolderStructure**

[image]

Comment: What error message/stacktrace are you getting?

Comment: @JohnWilliams sorry, I added it now.

Answer (score 0):

Your GenerationType of IDENTITY and the column definition of AUTO_INCREMENT looks [correct for MySQL](https://thorben-janssen.com/5-things-you-need-to-know-when-using-hibernate-with-mysql/)

Try the following:

```
@Column(name = "todo_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
```

It is strange for me that you have the JPA annotations and hbm.xml but that might be because I only work with JPA. Possibly the hbm.xml takes precedence over the JPA annotations, [try](https://www.javatpoint.com/generator-classes):

```
<id name="id" type="long" column="todo_id">
    <generator class="identity"/>
</id>
```

Comment: Tried, but doesn't work, I think that I probably should use only persistence.xml or hibernate.cfg.xml; anyway don't know what should I use/prefer.